# get_permalink() returns in wrong format via AJAX

Tags: ajax

In short, we have a CPT, we display the post on a page and we have a filter that uses AJAX.
The loop on the page and in the AJAX script both use the same template file to actually show the posts.
Permalinks are set to `/%postname%/`.

The title, text, image and extra info fields is all displayed correctly both on the initial page and the AJAX results.

But the permalink is not the same. We use `get_permalink($postid)` to get them.
On the initial page load, the permalinks are correct, with the postname.
On the results returned by the AJAX script, the permalinks are like: `?p=100`

Any idea what might cause this?

Comment: Are you using [`wp_ajax_{$action}` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_ajax_action/) to process your AJAX call or are you using something else?

Comment: @Howdy_McGee no, the wp_ajax action was taking to long to be usefull.

Comment: I would recommend [editing your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/414540/edit) with an explanation on how you're making your AJAX call and the code you're using. The `wp_ajax_` hook is really the recommended method. Any other method is likely going to need workarounds depending on what's being called, used, where, and why.